# How do I load this nested dictionary into ElasticSearch in Python?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have data that looks like this:

```
df =     {
        "3498573": [
            {
                "274985537": 0.43453,
                "274933900": 0.5344,
                "27845502": 0.32359
            }
        ],
        "4394879": [
            {
                "932847": 0.23984734
                "3454325": 0.2398472
            }
        ]
    }
```

It is a nested dictionary inside a list inside a dictionary.

Another way of representing it would be:

```
{
    "customer_id": [
        {
            "p_id": score,
            "p_id": score,
            "p_id": score
        }
    ],
    "customer_id": [
        {
            "p_id": score
            "p_id": score
        }
    ]
}
```

I am wondering how to get this data indexed into ElasticSearch. I am using the elasticsearch python API and I have created the mapping as follows:

```
request_body = {
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },

    'mappings': {
        'recommended': {
            'properties': {
                'customer_id': {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "master_product_id": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "score": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }}}
}
print("creating 'example_index' index...")
es.indices.create(index = 'example_index2', body = request_body)
```

I am getting a <400> error when trying to directly load the data like this:

```
import requests


requests.post(address, data=df, headers=headers)
```

Would I need to shape the data differently, like the following, in order for it to load? If so, how do I shape it like that?

```
nested = ({

    "customer_id": "13984209",
    "recommended_products": [
        {
            "master_product_id": "945873",
            "score": 0.94879437
        }
    ],
    "customer_id": "309248",
    "recommended_products": [
        {
            "master_product_id": "2383",
            "score": 0.36367326
        }
    ]

})
```

Comment: post the complete requests part

Comment: headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

requests.post('address/example_index/example_doc/_bulk', data=df, headers=headers)

Comment: try change from data=df to json=df

Comment: also post the complete response message